# What is the field of study of this algorithm problem?

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

In my app people can give a mark to other people out of ten points. At midnight, every day, I would like to implement an algorithm that compute the best "match" for each person. 
At the end of the day, I will have, for exemple :

```
(ID_person_who_gave_mark, ID_person_who_received_mark, mark)

(1, 2, 7.5)  // 1 gave to 2 a 7.5/10 
(1, 3, 9) // etc..
(1, 4, 6)
(2, 1, 5.5) 
(2, 3, 4)
(2, 4, 8)
(3, 1, 3)
(3, 2, 10) 
(3, 4, 9)
(4, 1, 2)
// no (4, 2, xx) because 4 didn't gave any mark to 2 
(4, 3, 6.5)
```

At the end of algo, I would like that every person has the best match, that is the best compromise to "make everyone happy".

In my exemple, I would say that person 1 gave a 9/10 to 3 but 3 gave a 3/10 to 1 so they definitely can't match, 1 gave a 7.5/10 to 2 and 2 gave a 5.5/10 to 1, so why not, and finally, 1 gave a 6/10 to 4 but 4 gave a 2/10 to 1 so they can't match (under 5/10 = they can't match). So for person 1, the only match would be with 2, but I have to check if it's good for 2 to have 1 as match too.

2 gave a 4/10 to 3 so (2,3) is over (under 5/10), but 2 gave a 8/10 to 4, so (2,4) would be much more cool for 2 than (2,1). 
Let's see 4 : 4 didn't gave any mark to 2, so they can't match : one possibility is left for 2 : we make the match (2-1)

let's see for 3 : with 1 it's over (3/10), with 2 it would be super cool for 3 (10/10) but 2 gave 3 a 4/10 so it's over. 3 gave a cool 9/10 to 4, so that would be nice too. Let's check 4 : 4 gave 2/10 to 1 so it's over with 1 (under 5/10), and gave a pretty nice 6.5 to 3. So the best match is finally between 4 and 3.

So our final matchs are in this exemple : (1-2) and (3-4)

Even when I do that intuitively like I just did, it's complicated to find an appropriate behaviour to compute all these informations.

Can you help me "mathematise" such a purpose, in order to have an algo that could do such calculation for let's say 50000 people ? Or at least, what is the field of study where I could get more information to solve this effectively  ?

Comment: Start with the [assignment-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), reason about it and look if it's fitting in terms of your objective. Even if chosen as backbone-algorithm, there are still lots of modelling decisions like how to fill the table (sum vs. sum of squares vs...; somewhat relates to l1-norm and l2-norm based error/losses in machine-learning). Additionally, while being one of the most researched problems having a large body of beautiful math results, it's still questionable, if your problem size of 50k will be fun (cubic complexity).

Comment: Thanks! that looks like precisely what I was looking for :) I will read further on wikipedia. Has artificial intelligence something to do with it ?

Comment: Look at [stable marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) problem as well.

Comment: After I read about all this, Assignment problem and stable mariage problem are for 2 classes that need to be paired with each other (task with jobs and men and women). In my case, mathematically speaking I need to find a maximum sized matching for my graph where sum of all edges weight is maximum. Would you know an algo finding this ?